# Laravel Faker limit outputs (also: a simple way to create your own faker provider)

Tags: laravel, faker

I've been successfully populating my db-tables with Laravel's faker.

```
destination' => $faker->country
```

countries? (doesn't matter which actually).

For example when creating 10 rows in my database, I want to have only 2 countries to appear: Egypt, Turkey, Turkey, Turkey, Egypt, Turkey, Egypt, Turkey, Turkey, Egypt.

(The names of the countries actually don't matter, it matters to have only 2 distinct countries in the output).

Answer (score 1):

figured it out myself:

```
'destination' => $faker->randomElement($array = array ('Turkey','Egypt'))
```

Comment: Great. I would vote for this if more explanation was provided about why this solution works, and the lesson learned.

Comment: https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerproviderbase
just read the official documentation:)
there is an option to seed the base with elements of array you create yourself. ($faker-> randomElement($array = arra ('abc', 'def'....))
that's basically all the explanation, my friend:)